# Writing a file into separate new files

Tags: c

Suppose I read a file into a buffer:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("data.dat", "rb");    
double *buf = calloc(100, sizeof(double));
fread(buf, sizeof(double),100, fp);
```

My goal is to re-write the loaded file into two separate files each of which has 50 elements (First 50 goes to file and the last 50 goes to another one). I do the following:

```
    int c;
    FILE *fp_w= NULL;
    for (c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
        sprintf(filename, "file_%d%s", c, ".dat");
        fp_w = fopen(filename, "wb");
        fseek(fp_w, 50*sizeof(double), SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(buf, sizeof(double), 50, fp_w);

    }
    fclose(fp_w);
```

However, I don't actually get the correct division. In other words, I feel the pointer `fp_w` does not move to the position 50 very well and I don't know how to handle `fseek` in another way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Move `fclose(fp_w);`  into the loop.

Comment: I don't understand the need to `fseek` in the newly created file. And you are writing the first half of the buffer into each file.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, each half should go to a unique file.

Comment: I think we understand that, but you are writing the first half ino each file, and doing nothing with the second half. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many issues:

1. You don't close the file once you have written to it
2. You seek into the file to write whithout any need
3. You write twice the same buffer to both files.

You probably need this:

```
int c;
FILE *fp_w= NULL;
for (c = 0; c < 2; ++c) {
    sprintf(filename, "file_%d%s", c, ".dat");
    fp_w = fopen(filename, "wb");              

    // buf + 50*c to get the right part of the buffer
    // (buf for the first part and buf+50 for the second part)
    fwrite(buf + 50*c, sizeof(double), 50, fp_w);

    // close file right here, not outside the loop
    fclose(fp_w);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting these issues. Very clean answer. Appreciate it.